# How to configure custom log file in java web project

Tags: java, log4j, jboss5.x

I am developing a java web application using eclipse IDE and jboss server (version 5). I am trying to implement a custom log file for my application with the following code :

```
FileAppender fileAppender=new FileAppender(newPatternLayout(),Constant.LOGGER_PATH);
logger.addAppender(fileAppender);
BasicConfigurator.configure();
logger.setLevel(Level.ERROR);
logger.error(cause);
```

When I am trying to deploy my application to the jboss server it gives following exception :

```
    18:35:16,346 ERROR [STDERR] log4j:ERROR A "org.jboss.logging.util.OnlyOnceError
    andler" object is not assignable to a "org.apache.log4j.spi.ErrorHandler" varia
    le.
    18:35:16,346 ERROR [STDERR] log4j:ERROR The class "org.apache.log4j.spi.ErrorHa
    dler" was loaded by
    18:35:16,346 ERROR [STDERR] log4j:ERROR [WebappClassLoader
      delegate: false
      repositories:
        /WEB-INF/classes/
    ----------> Parent Classloader:
    java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader@893918
    ] whereas object of type
    18:35:16,346 ERROR [STDERR] log4j:ERROR "org.jboss.logging.util.OnlyOnceErrorHa
    dler" was loaded by [org.jboss.system.server.NoAnnotationURLClassLoader@a32b].
    18:35:16,377 ERROR [STDERR] log4j:ERROR Could not create an Appender. Reported
    rror follows.
    18:35:16,377 ERROR [STDERR] java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jboss.logging.app
    nder.DailyRollingFileAppender cannot be cast to org.apache.log4j.Appender
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your application has its own copy of log4j.jar bundles into its `lib` directory.  This will clash with JBoss's own copy.

Remove that JAR from the `lib` directory and try again, your app will use the JBoss copy.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but due to some problem in the client's hosting server, no log data is printing on the server log. That's why I have to implement this Custom log file. Can I avoid this clash with the help of any code. If something is there, please help me.

Comment: @user1401030: Your custom logger will still work when you take the log4j JAR out of the app. It will use JBoss's copy of the JAR.

Comment: Thank a lot for your suggestion. It really helped me to overcome my problem.